# Create a TreeMap from nested list using Java Streams

Tags: java, algorithm, java-8, java-stream, treemap

**Given:**
I have `List<List<Integer>> locations` which is coordinates of a location. For example Place A: (2,4), Place B: (5,4), Place C: (10,9), Place D: (2,4). So my `locations` would contain of list of lists. *I am unable to change this format.*

The cost to go to a specific location is the square root of the sum of the coordinates. So to go to the cost is `Place A = Math.sqrt(2 + 4)`, cost to go to `Place B = Math.sqrt(5 + 4)` and so on.

**Output**: What I'm trying to get is a list of the least 'cost' of all the locations. The requirement for the return is `List<List<Integer>> nearestLocations`. What I did is I'm trying to create a `TreeMap<Double, List<List<Integer>>`

**Question**  my question is how do I convert the convert the below using Java 8 streams?

```
 List<List<Integer>> findNearestLocation(int total, List<List<Integer>> allLocations, int size) {
        ArrayList<List<Integer>> results = new ArrayList<>();
        TreeMap<Double, List<Integer>> map = new TreeMap<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < total && i < allLocations.size(); i++) {
            List<Integer> list = allLocations.get(i);
            double l = 0.0;
            for (Integer x : list) {
                l += x * x;
            }
            map.put(Math.sqrt(l), list);
        }
        if (map.size() > 0) {
            for (int get = 0; get < size; get++) {
                results.add(map.get(map.firstKey()));
                map.remove(map.firstKey());
            }

        }
        return results;
    }
```

Comment: Your solution seems to compute a map where keys are the actual costs, whereas you seem to want to be able to lookup by `place`. Also, where is the "place" defined in your initial `List<List<Integer>> locations` input? The index in the outer list?

Comment: the "place" is just pseudo meaning of why the input is structured this way. it is actually just a `List<List<Integer>> locations`. there is no Place object. @ernest_k

Comment: "I can do it through multiple iterations through multiple for each" - how about you post that code, so it's easier for us to understand what exactly you're looking for?

Comment: @daniu I've added the manual iterations

Comment: Wait, you just want to sort the list by the square root of their elements?

Comment: @daniu in a way but I need to return a `List<List<Integer>>` that represents the places

Comment: Are you just looking for the `N cheapest coordinates`? (cheap being defined by cost as per your formula)

Comment: @ernest_k yes in `List<List<Integer>>` form

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Map` is actually `Map<Double, List<Integer>>`

Your current code return just `Map` if you want `TreeMap` you need:

```
    TreeMap<Double, List<List<Integer>>> x = locations.stream().collect(
            Collectors.groupingBy((List<Integer> b) -> {
                        double d = b.stream().mapToDouble(i -> i.doubleValue()).sum();
                        return Math.sqrt(d);
                    },
                    TreeMap::new,
                    Collectors.toList()));
```

PS: You distance is not usual euclidean distance. To make it so you need `i -> i.doubleValue() * i.doubleValue()`

Comment: I see you are throwing a runtime exception, I need the return value to be a List<List<Integer>> to be the return type, so on collision I am trying to append the list rather than throwing RunTimeException

Comment: @mel3kings fixed that.

Comment: `locations.stream().collect(
                Collectors.groupingBy(b -> Math.sqrt(b.stream().mapToDouble(Integer::doubleValue).sum()),
                        TreeMap::new,
                        Collectors.toList()));`

Comment: You should insert the multiplication into the code instead of only mention it afterwards. You can do it as simple as `.mapToDouble(i -> i * i)` or, if you fear integer overflow, use `.mapToDouble(i -> i * (double)i)`. There is, by the way, no need to calculate the `sqrt` when you use that value only for sorting.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to sort that list by their distance, you can just do

```
Collections.sort(list, (list1, list2) -> 
    Double.compare(Math.sqrt(list1.get(0) + list1.get(1)),
                   Math.sqrt(list2.get(0) + list2.get(1))));
```

or on a copy of the list if the initial list is immutable.

Comment: I think you're very close. Check [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/95120580?noredirect=1). I think you need to return just a sublist after the sort

Comment: @ernest_k Yeah I've noticed, but a) that's not in the actual problem statement, and b) calling `sublist` on the result is somewhat trivial.

Comment: When you use the lambda syntax with curly braces, you need a `return` statement. For the expression syntax, remove the `{` and `}`. And actually, you need `sqrt(x*x + y*y)` rather than `sqrt(x + y)`. But on the other hand, to determine the ordering, you can omit the expensive `sqrt` calculation, as it doesn’t affect the order. So you may use `Collections.sort(list, Comparator.comparingInt(l -> l.get(0)*l.get(0) + l.get(1)*l.get(1)));`